# put current date to a cell if it is filled with zapier

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this script:

```
function onEdit () {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet (); 
    if (s.getName () == "sheet_name") { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell (); 
    if (r.getColumn () == 1) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset (0, 1); 
    if (nextCell.getValue () === '')  
    nextCell.setValue (new Date()); 
} 
} 
}
```

It works if I fill one cell by myself and puts current date to another cell in the right.
BUT if I use Zapier to export my data from Todoist to Google Sheets this script doesn't work. It only works if I change something manually.

Is there any way to make a script which will fill a cell I need with a today date when Zapier export data and fills cells automatically?

Comment: In this case, please use the installed OnChange trigger instead of the OnEdit trigger and test it again.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with dummy values to identify the structure of your sheet ? The reason would be to identify what range of columns needs to be isolated

Comment: @Tanaike you suggestion didn't work. in fact the scrip stopped do anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `you suggestion didn't work. in fact the scrip stopped do anything at all.`, I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I have to study more.

Comment: @CenturyTuna I am not sure.. is this what you asked? https://i.ibb.co/L8jCCrS/image.png

Comment: @Tanaike I feel a sarcasm in your answer.... Maybe I somehow offended you in my comment? I apologize if i did. I didn't want to do that. Just told that it didn't help...

Comment: About `I feel a sarcasm in your answer.... Maybe I somehow offended you in my comment? I apologize if i did. I didn't want to do that. Just told that it didn't help... `, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I'm not angry. Please don't worry. I thought that from your reply, the reason, that my comment was not useful, is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: My English skill is poor. I'm always worried whether my answer and comment are required to be modified. If my English for apologizing was not correct, I apologize again. At that time, please tell me.

Comment: @Johnny there are still some stuff that isn't clear. First off we need to know which of those data came from the Zapier Export, and clarify on which column would the date be populated from the script. Also we need some clarification if the data only updates existing cells or does it populate new rows everytime the Zap is run

Comment: @CenturyTuna well "date to export" is a column where to export. it is blank, i just wrote "DATE" there to clarify where it should be. Data pops new rows I (I think so, I dont know what exactly Zapier do when it export data), But if you manually copy and paste (for example) 4 rows this script also won't work in 2-3-4 cells and will put date only in 1 cell. Looks like Zapier does something like that... and it fills only the cells I want, column 2 is not silled with anything when Zapier export data it remains blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

As what Tanaike mentioned, you need to rename your function to something else aside from `onEdit()` since onEdit is a reserved function name for App Script and use `onChange` trigger.

But based on how Zapier works, the reason why the current code you have provided is not working is because exports from Zapier is not detected as an active cell, so we would need to revamp the entire code.

**Try this instead:**

```
function onZapierUpdate() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); //my test sheet is Sheet2
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, 2);
  var data = range.getValues();
  data.forEach(x => x[0] != "" ? x[1] = new Date() : x);
  range.setValues(data);

}
```

After saving the script, set this on an `onChange` trigger like so:[image]

Now whenever Zapier exports the data, it changes the content of the spreadsheet which means `onChange` trigger will take effect. [image]

**Reference:**
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()